# Plotting with ggord multiple variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, lda

I am a bit lost coming frome [here](https://fawda123.github.io/ggord/reference/ggord.html) because as I see with few variables the function is capable of creating visible vectors. Instead, my syntax tends to overlap vector creating a net without visibility.
The LDA is calculated for a set of multiple variables (genomic expression in particular, ~50 genes) in 3 groups (categorical variable = grup_int)

```
#simple syntax

ggord::ggord(model1, ldat2$grup_int,  size = 1, ylim = c(-4,4))
```

[image]

Now I will post something I am looking for with iris database to show similarities of what I want

```
library(MASS)
res <- lda(Species ~ . , iris)
res

fd <- predict(res, iris)$x  # puntuación den las funciones discriminantes
coef(lm(fd ~ .-Species,iris))


iris2 <- iris
iris2[,1:4] <- scale(iris2[,1:4])
lda(Species ~ . , iris2)$scaling


plot(res, pch=19, col=as.integer(iris[,5]))


predicho <- predict(res, iris)
str(predicho)
predicho$class


table(iris[,5], predicho$class)


res.cv <- lda(Species ~ . , iris, CV=TRUE)


tc <- table(iris[,5], res.cv$class)
tc


prednew <- predict(res, newdata=data.frame(Sepal.Length=5, Sepal.Width=3, Petal.Length=2.5, Petal.Width=0.3))
prednew


fd <- predict(res,iris)$x
medias <- sapply(1:3, function(grupo) colMeans(fd[iris[,5]==levels(iris[,5])[grupo],]))
plot(fd, pch=19, col=as.integer(iris[,5]), asp=1)
points(medias[1,],medias[2,],pch="+",cex=2, col=1:3)
points(prednew$x,col="blue",pch=19)

lines(c(prednew$x[1],medias[1,1]),c(prednew$x[2],medias[2,1]),lty=2,col=1)
lines(c(prednew$x[1],medias[1,2]),c(prednew$x[2],medias[2,2]),lty=2,col=2)
lines(c(prednew$x[1],medias[1,3]),c(prednew$x[2],medias[2,3]),lty=2,col=3)

library(cluster)
D<-daisy(rbind(prednew$x,t(medias)),"euclidean")
mtext(paste("Distancia:",round(D[1],3)),col=1,line=2)
mtext(paste("Distancia:",round(D[2],3)),col=2,line=1)
mtext(paste("Distancia:",round(D[3],3)),col=3,line=0)
```

The graph with lines between groups, if it is possible[image]